# How to set the Pin in bluetooth pairing in Windows 8

Tags: windows, bluetooth

I am trying to programmatically pair my Windows 8 notebook with an android device.

I am using the Windows [bluetooth API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa362883%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

```
    NativeMethods.BluetoothRegisterForAuthenticationEx(ref device, out m_regHandle, myCallback, IntPtr.Zero);

    BLUETOOTH_DEVICE_INFO btDevice= new BLUETOOTH_DEVICE_INFO(device.ToInt64());
      byte[] pbtOobData = (byte[]) null;
string myPin = "357689"
            NativeMethods.BluetoothAuthenticateDevice(IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, ref btDevice, myPin, myPin.Length);
```

These are the Pinvoke declarations:

```
    [DllImport("Irprops.cpl", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
        internal extern static int BluetoothAuthenticateDevice(IntPtr hwndParent, IntPtr hRadio, ref BLUETOOTH_DEVICE_INFO pbtdi, string pszPasskey, int ulPasskeyLength);

  [DllImport("bthprops.cpl", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
       internal extern static uint BluetoothRegisterForAuthenticationEx(ref BLUETOOTH_DEVICE_INFO pbtdi, out BluetoothAuthenticationRegistrationHandle phRegHandle, NativeMethods.BluetoothAuthenticationCallbackEx pfnCallback, IntPtr pvParam);
```

I can pair the devices using this method, and I can see that I get a pair request in the device. but the problem is that the PIN in the request is not the one that I specified.

How can I set my own PIN?

Comment: In bluetooth pairing for devices with BT stack 2.1 or above, if both devices have capability to display and enter passkey , passkey is generated from the device controller and send to user to confirm that passkey generated on both the devices are same, passkey is not transmitted to other device(Simple Secure pairing/SSP). That may be the main reason that passkey is not same . Not sure on windows programming :)